# Ruby / Rails news feeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I quite enjoy receiving weekly newsletters from rubyweekly.com. It keeps me up to speed with the Ruby / Rails community and new developments. I was wondering if there are any other sites similar to this one?

So far I have come across:

- rubyflow.com
- rubyinside.com
- railsinside.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a newsletter, but I like the Ruby5 podcast and site. It keeps me up to speed in the Ruby world.

http://ruby5.envylabs.com/

Answer (score 1):

railscasts.com is great but it's videos rather than text.

Comment: I didn't remember the text version :)